# Blender video render output looks bad

Tags: rendering, animation, lighting

When i render my blender animation in with Eevee the scene looks ugly in the video:

[image]

But in the render tab, where you can follow your rendering process, the video looks much better:

[image]

Why the qualitiy is bad in the video output, but not while the rendering process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what your screenshots are highlighting, maybe some color banding?

The thing is, what you see in Blender is the raw render output as it is when delivered by the GPU or CPU. What you get in a video file is a different data that might have been compressed depending the output settings you have used.

Typically if you set a h264 encoding, with Blender's default encoding settings, then it's a compressed result with a medium-low image quality most of the time. Which results in heavy color banding, boxings, loss of color constrats, ...

If you want a better quality, you have to setup a better render output. Though the usual workflow is almost never to do the 3D rendering and video compressing at the same time, we usually render into lossles or uncompressed picture files (exr for later editing, or targa), and only then we assemble everything into a video. This workflow also makes it easier to recover in case of crash while rendering, as well as do frame-specific updates.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You helped me a lot. Now it works fine. Thanks!